# Session Like Singleton in Blazor Server Side

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

One of the problems of Blazor Server side is its Singleton and Scoped services, Its singleton is shared between all users making it act like a cache, And scoped service is lost on refresh, I solved this problem to have a Singleton service that is not shared like the following:
First we require two services:

```
  namespace BlazorStore9.Services
  {
    public class MZSingleton
    {
        public Dictionary<Guid, Cart> Carts { get; set; } = new Dictionary<Guid, Cart>();
    }

    public class MZScopedSessionID
    {
        public Guid SessionID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then register them as Singleton and Scoped respectively, And inject them in the Layout pages and other pages or components that need it, The following is a Layout page, That stores and retrives sessionID using Local Storage:

```
@inject IJsInterop jsInterop
@inject MZSingleton mzSingleton
@inject MZScopedSessionID sessionID

    @code
    {
        private BlazorStore9.Services.Cart cart = null;

        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);

            #region some imp codes
            if (firstRender)
            {
                string SessionIDString = await jsInterop.GetAccessToken("SessionID"); 
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionIDString) || !Guid.TryParse(SessionIDString, out Guid theGuid))
                {
                    Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
                    await jsInterop.SaveAccessToken("SessionID", id.ToString());
                    sessionID.SessionID = id;
                    mzSingleton.Carts[sessionID.SessionID] = new Cart();                
                }
                else
                {
                    sessionID.SessionID = Guid.Parse(SessionIDString);
                    if (!mzSingleton.Carts.ContainsKey(sessionID.SessionID))
                        mzSingleton.Carts[sessionID.SessionID] = new Cart();                
                }

                cart = mzSingleton.Carts[sessionID.SessionID];
           }
    }
```

Then in each page or component we have:

```
@inject MZSingleton mzSingleton
@inject MZScopedSessionID sessionID

@code
{
     private Cart cart = null;

     protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
     {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        cart = mzSingleton.Carts[sessionID.SessionID];
     }
}
```

My question is, If this aproach is secure for using with Authentication purposes? Here I showed only a shopping cart that could not be secure, but what for Authentication purposes?

Comment: Ignoring your misguided attempt to store semi-persistent data inside a process there is nothing particularly wrong with using random value (that is long enough for your security requirements) store in cookie as key to "session". I.e. it is exactly how session is implemented... (Custom authentication approaches are known to be bad in pretty much 110% of cases, but again since you are not doing anything real inventing your own auth should be ok too)

Comment: I have a real website waiting to be uploaded and used, I choose to implement this approach as its authentication, But you say this is flawed, So I feel your definite answer is not to use this approach in production.

Comment: I suggest you give [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-3.1) a good once over, this very thing is discussed.